# using linked images in reporting services report?

Tags: reporting-services

We have a location on our intranet that contains various versions of our logo. Rather than embedding an image in my reports I want to http link to the appropriate image on our intranet. 
Is this possible?

TIA
J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

It is necessary that in the options when adding image choose "External" for the "Select Image Source" and simply copying the link of image in the textbox "Use this image"